# How to align (georeference) images using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, coordinate-system, china

I'm completely new to all this.

I'm trying to make a map of Han dynasty-era China for a mod for a game called Crusader Kings 2.

I've downloaded QGIS and Natural Earth 2, but I need this **[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWtDi.jpg)** to align with the rest of the map so I can use it as a guide for province boundaries.

I tried georeferencing the image, and I managed to get it added as a layer, but even with on-the-fly projection conversion, QGIS refused to show it at the same time as any other layer.

This was the **[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJlDm.jpg)**.

I'm also open to suggestions on any simpler methods I could use if QGIS is overkill for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Welcome to GIS-SE!  By "the program refused" do you mean "QGIS refused" or "Crusader Kings 2 refused"?

Comment: QGIS refused to show the layer with other layers. With some fiddling, I managed to get this: http://i.imgur.com/acfFDZU.jpg but as you can see the map features don't match the points although it's much closer than the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not georeferenced using QGIS but I found a **[tutorial](http://geo.nls.uk/urbhist/guides_georeferencingqgis.html)** that says:

> In QGIS there are several methods for transforming the image, these
> include the linear / affine transformation, the Helmert, the 1st, 2nd
> and 3rd order polynomials, and the thin plate spline. These different
> Transformation Methods interpret your Control Points in different
> ways, and control how the map you are georeferencing is fitted and
> warped to your georeferenced base map.
>
> For best fit, the thin-plate
> spline or higher-number polynomial transformations are often best. The
> spline transformation, as a true rubber sheeting method, transforms
> the source Control Points exactly to the target Control Points, and
> optimises for local accuracy opposed to global accuracy.

I think you will get best results using a true rubber sheeting method (i.e. spline).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/CoTDSfO.jpg This is what I've managed to get with your advice, using spline instead of linear. Thanks so much.

Comment: Excellent - it's nice to see the result!

Comment: As a side matter, it's also nice to see the formation of major river deltas, too! @Craig